# VNC with Xinetd and xdmcp no longer work after upgrade to 18.04.4

Tags: vnc

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 desktop from DVD ISO and then enabled on-demand vnc service (tigervnc) with xinetd and xdmcp. Everything worked fine.

After I upgraded to the most recent packages (`apt upgrade -y`), I can still get a login screen and desktop. But if I open any application, the application window will become black, as shown below:

[image: application window is black]

Here is my configuration:

```
/etc/xinetd.d/vnc
```

[image: screenshot of file contents in terminal]

```
/etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

[image: screenshot of file contents in terminal]